# Creating an aging view

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We have a requirement to create a view which shows records with a create date that are Less than 3 days old, less than a week old, one week old, two weeks old.  How would you use the [Today] in a filter to do those ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a column (calculated) which add 3 days to created date - I call it "3daycolumn "(date only field)
2. Create another column (calculated) which adds 7 days to created date - I call it 1weekcolumn (date only field)
3. Create another column (calculated) which adds 14 days to created date - I call it 2weekscolumn (date only field)

Formula for above: =created +3 and so on...

Now create views for each step with the filter  [Today]

For View 1: is  equal to `[Today]` on column 3daycolumn

For View 2: is  equal to `[Today]` on column 1weekcolumn

for view 3: is  equal to `[Today]` on column 2weekscolumn

finally for less than week 
You need two filter on  greater than 3daycolumn and less than 1 week column.

Hope I answered your question
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For an OOTB solution, I would create a view for each group/age bracket and apply a filter on each, as below.

Created -> is greater than or equal to -> [Today]-n

'n' should be the desired number of days, so 3 for 3 days, 6 for 'less than 1 week', 7 for 'one week', 14 for 'two weeks', and so on.

If you wanted to display them all on the same page at one time, you may want to look into something like [Easy Tabs](http://usermanagedsolutions.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Easy-Tabs-v5.aspx).